# Disable mouse click on button click and enabling it again

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to disable mouse left click on button click for pdf. Now once we close the pdf, I want to enable it again.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgExportPDF" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/pdf-Export.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="imgExportPDF_Click" />
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to disable mouse left click on button

What about the space bar? Enter? Right mouse button for left-handed mouse?

Your solution Y ("Disable left click") to problem X ("User may not 'click' button") is wrong, see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You just want to set the button's `Enabled` property to `false`.